# Reading data from file adds extra spaces

Tags: c++

Im trying to code a program that reads a file then copies all of the data and stores it into another file. The code below does that but it adds extra bytes randomly in the file which makes the file 249KB instead of 243KB. Ive found that if i remove the "\n" it doesn't add any extra bytes but instead it removes bytes and makes it 237KB.

```
    std::wifstream in_file("initfs_Win32", std::ios::binary);
    in_file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    std::wstring in_data;

    if (in_file.good()) {
        while (std::getline(in_file, in_data))
            str_buf += in_data + L"\n"

        std::wofstream out_file("initfs");
        out_file << str_buf;

        out_file.close();
    }
    in_file.close();
```

Here is an image of the old (Right) and new (Left) files side by side:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sz8Dd.png)

Comment: Note: The left image has `0x0D0D0A` where the right image only has `0x0D0A`.  `0x0D` is CR (`\r`), and `0x0A` is LF (`\n`).

Comment: If you are going to copy binary files, use `ifstream::read()` and `ofstream::write()` - or use [`std::filesystem::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy)

Comment: Open the output stream in binary mode.

Comment: Also, to copy an input stream, just write out its buffer: `out_file << in_file.rd_buf();`.

Comment: If you are going to copy binary files, use the operating system, don't write a program to do it.  Operating Systems that support files have optimized the function for copying files.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy one file into another file don't do it line by line, do it this way instead:

```
std::ifstream source("initfs_Win32", std::ios::binary);
if (not source.is_open())
{
    std::cerr << "Error opening file" << std::endl;
}
std::ofstream destiny("initfs", std::ios::binary);
destiny << original.rdbuf();
destiny.close();
```